# Visual C# - Get accessor method returns 0 for value

Tags: c#, get, set, static-methods

I'm trying to pass method values along between forms. As a result, I've made the methods whose data I want to pass along static. Since I'm using non-static text boxes to gather user input, I've also made public property methods to parse the input from the user, store its value in a public class-level static variable, and return the value to the static methods which call the variable.

```
public static int laborHours;

public int lHoursB
{
  get
  {
    return laborHours;
  }
  set
  {
    laborHours = int.Parse(lHours.Text);
  }
}

private static decimal laborMethod(decimal laborTotal)
{
  const decimal laborCharge = 50M;
  decimal labor = 0;

  labor = laborCharge * laborHours;
  return labor;
}

public static decimal amountCharged;

public decimal amount
{
  get
  {
    return amountCharged;
  }
  set
  {
    amountCharged = int.Parse(amtBox.Text);
  }
} 

public static int numberOfParts;

public int partsNumber
{
  get
  {
    return numberOfParts;
  }
  set
  {
    numberOfParts = int.Parse(partsBox.Text);
  }
}

private static decimal subtotalMethod(decimal subTotal)
{
  decimal subtotal = 0;

  subtotal = amountCharged * numberOfParts;

  return subtotal;
}

private static decimal subtotal2Method(decimal subtotalTwo)
{
  decimal labor = 0;
  decimal subtotal = 0;

  labor = laborMethod(labor);
  subtotal = subtotalMethod(subtotal);
  subtotalTwo = subtotal + labor;

  return subtotalTwo;
}

private static decimal taxMethod(decimal salesTax)
{
  const decimal tax = .08M;
  decimal sTax = 0;
  decimal sub = 0;
  sub = subtotalMethod(sub);

  sTax = sub * tax;

  return sTax;
}
```

The compiler checks everything out as a clean compile, but there's a logic error here I can't seem to find. When I run a simple test with the program, every text box returns a "0".

Help, please?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong. But you shouldn't use static fields/methods in this way. Create a class that define the fields you want to expose for the other forms and use it to carry the state in and out forms.

Comment: The property setters are very, very odd here, as well...

Comment: Also, in all methods but one, the parameter is never used. Why have a parameter then?

Comment: Agree with devundef and Reed Cosey above. @OP - Is this a Windows or Web app?

Comment: Please show the code where you are setting the textbox Text property.

Comment: Static fields and instance (non-static) accessors makes precisely no sense. Nor does ignoring "value" in a setter. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Your properties are back to front compared to the normal way they are written. I suggest you write them like this instead:

```
public int lHoursB
{   
  get
  {
    int result = 0;
    int.TryParse(lHours.Text, out result);
    return result;
  }
  set
  {
    lHours.Text = value.ToString();
  }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
lHoursB = 10;
```

which will set the lHours textbox to "10". I have used TryParse and not Parse, as the latter will throw a FormatException if it cannot parse the string; you may prefer to have an exception, in which case use Parse. Also you should use Decimal.Parse/TryParse and not Int32.Parse for amount, which is a decimal and not an int. Finally, you can specify a culture in the int.ToString call, if you want to format the int for a specific culture (see [Int32.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cht2hdff)).